# I want to run an rsync command at midnight but make it stop at 8am. How can i schedule the start AND END of a command?

Tags: macos, bash, command-line, operating-systems, crontab

I want to run an rsync command at midnight but make it stop at 8am. How can i schedule the start AND END of a command?

I've looked into cronjobs but that will only start at a certain time. Any ideas on how to end this process? Ill be running it from OS X. I thought about logging in as a new ssh user and just using a cronjob to start a bash script to kill that connection but that seems like overwork.

Comment: Have you tried using ulimit -t to cap the amount of time it can execute?

Comment: @RandyHoward: `ulimit -t` will limit the CPU time used, but rsync generally uses very little CPU, being limited by I/O.

Answer (score 3):

Add a second `crontab` entry that kills `rsync` at 8 am. Another option would be to start `rsync` in the background and have the script loop until 8 am before it kills the process:

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync ... &
pid=$!

while /bin/true; do
  if [ $(date +%H) -ge 8 ]; then
    kill -TERM $pid
    exit 0
  else
    sleep 60
  fi
done
```

Comment: Could you give me the official URL to the explanation of '$!'? I couldn't google it coz it's somewhat recognized as special characters by Google.

Comment: @Judking It's documented in the section PARAMETERS of the [`bash` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html) (under "Special Parameters"). It's also explained in [chapter 9.1 of the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) (under "Other Special Parameters").

Answer (score 3):

You could have a shell script write the rsync PID into a file at a fixed location. I would get the PID by launching rsync in the background (append &) and use `$!`.

```
rsync blah/ remote:blah/ &
echo $! > pidfile
```

Then another cron job at 8 am would read that file and put the result into RSPID.

```
RSPID=`cat pidfile`
```

Then run `ps $RSPID | grep rsync` to see if it is still running, then do `kill $RSPID`.

Something along those lines should work.

You could also put the kill command into the shell script. Launch rsync in the background and sleep 8 hours, then kill the rsync.

Answer (score 3):

At some point fairly recently [rsync added](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/43335) arguments for stopping at a fixed time.

This means you can now call

```
rsync --stop-at 08:00
```

which, provided you started running at midnight via cron will do exactly what you want very simply.